# REGEX : Must include only letter,number or character

Tags: regex

I have the following REGEX

```
/^(?!.* )(?=.*[!@#$\.%^&])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])$/
```

it should not allow white space and contains a letter a digit and a character.

But I would like to have the following

do not contain space, and contains any of `[!@#$\.%^&]`, `digits` and character, so `aaaaaaaa` or `!!!!!!!!` would work.

but I can7t find how to validate the lot

Comment: Your regex is pretty close.  Just try adding `.*` before `$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Here is [Online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KUCPA1/1/)

```
^[!#$a-z.%^&\dA-Z@]+$
```

***Explanation:*** Simply looking for `!#$a-z.%^&\dA-Z@` characters from starting to end of the string if only these come then match the string if anything else is coming apart from these then don't match the string.